# Install Whitebox to QGIS

Tags: qgis, whitebox-gat, whitebox-tools

I am working in QGIS 4.8, and I am trying to use the Whitebox Processing plugin. I have Whitebox Tools and Whitebox GAT zip files installed and unzipped on my drive. However, I cannot use the Whitebox Processing plugin, and Whitebox isn't showing up as a provider. Has anyone else faced this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using QGIS 3.8.1 (not sure what QGIS version 4.8 is. Perhaps a typo?):

Add the Alex Bruy QGIS plugin repository to your QGIS Repository list:
(Caveat: Adding unofficial/3rd party repositories must be done at your own risk)

Plugins -> Manage and Install Plugins -> Settings -> Add
https://plugins.bruy.me/plugins/plugins.xml
[image]

Download/extract WhiteBoxTools to an appropriate location on your machine such as C:\WBTools\
https://jblindsay.github.io/ghrg/WhiteboxTools/download.html

Configure the WhiteBox Tools Provider:
Settings -> Options -> Processing -> Providers
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean 3.8.   Try adding Alex Bruy's repository to the QGIS Plugins and add Whitebox from it.  To do this go to the QGIS Plug in settings and in the Plugin repositories click Add and put in https://plugins.bruy.me/plugins/plugins.xml.  (That is the current path, but in the future if it doesn't work look for a link to his repository on his plugins webpage.  I'd skip trying to add his plugins from Github directly.)  Then you should see a bunch of new plugins to install in your QGIS and one of those should be Whitebox.  One more step. As Bruy notes on his plugins site, you first need to download and install Whitebox tools  (he gives you a link) and you will need to go to Processing Toolbox options (wrench symbol) and in the providers tell Whitebox processing where the Whitebox tools exe is located.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! This worked!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is the best walk-trough (and it is being updated regularly, in case anything changes).

**From the official documentation:**
https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/manual/wbt_book/qgis_plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

Since January 2023, the WhiteboxTools for QGIS is included in official QGIS plugin repository, no need of adding special repo. Works with QGIS 3.18 and higher. See official documentation: https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/manual/wbt_book/qgis_plugin.html