# Whitebox for Processing 0.15.0 plugin in QGIS 3.10.0

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, whitebox-tools

I'm trying to use the Whitebox for Processing (v 0.15.0) plugin in QGIS 3.10.0 on Windows 10. When I attempt to run a tool, I receive the following in the tool log:

```
WhiteboxTools command output:
'"whitebox_tools"' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I unzipped WhiteBoxTools, which I downloaded from https://jblindsay.github.io/ghrg/WhiteboxTools/download.html, in "C:\Programs Files". I added the path to the whitebox_tools.exe to the registry and the folder containing it to the PATH variable. This didn't change anything.

I have tried to change the processing provider in QGIS options (as recommended [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331316/install-whitebox-to-qgis) ), but there is no drop down option available for WhiteboxTools, as in the below image
[image: Processing options for QGIS]

Does anyone have any idea how to rectify this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to double click on the right part of the label "WhiteboxTools executable" to fill in the path.

See screenshot below:

[image: WhiteboxTools executable path configuration]

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! Never would have known there was a dialog box there

Comment: Thanks for that! I tried pasting in the path and found it didn't work, but it did when I used the dotdotdot button to select the exe file. (QGIS 3.14)